# Is it Possible to extract the name of an Argument in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, function, arguments, typescript-generics, namedtuple

Using `Parameters` I can get the argument types, even as named tuple, but how can I access the name of the argument (or the tuple for that matter), is it possible in the latest TypeScript Version (5.1.6)?

```js
type MyFunction = (argumentName: number) => void

type FirstArgumentType<F extends ((p:any)=>any)> = Parameters<F>[0] 
type FirstArgumentName<F extends ((p:any)=>any)> = ... 

type T0 = Parameters<MyFunction> // [argumentName: number]
type T1 = FirstArgumentType<MyFunction> // number
type T2 = FirstArgumentName<MyFunction> // argumentName
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=56&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgY2ASwPbKgXigAoBDAJwHNEBbCZYAOWJoC4plqAjCUgSnwD4oANywYAJgFgAUNNCQo8DKQDOwAIIVqtYABVwEADzwoEAB7BaY5UUJhmxZCB55%20Dp4IIAFMkwgWVRvwA2gAMALpQsvoKSqoalDR0jDRGJuaW1oS29o7OrrkeUAB0JZEyUnLQOiH4UN6kvv7KBnBIaJg4ggD0XVBBZAnayRCs7FRcpGFR8joAjLWKKuqaibr6LQgo6NjI3b1jE9NVAEwLscuDSb4bbdudUD1QA1pXNNJAA)

Essentially I want a type helper that returns `argumentName` given `(argumentName: number) => void`, is that possible TypeScript?

I suppose this GitHub Issue is somewhat related, but it gives me no clue what else I could look up https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49122

Comment: As it mentioned in the Github issue, it's not possible today :(

Comment: Sadly, your playground link has been hit by [this SO bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386543/why-does-my-typescript-playground-link-break-when-i-use-insert-hyperlink); see the workaround in that link.

Comment: Minor terminology note to help with searching, etc: If I'm reading your question right, you're looking for the *parameter* name, not the *argument* name. (Arguments don't have names in JavaScript/TypeScript as far as I know, they're just values.) For instance, in `type MyFunction = (argumentName: number) => void`, if you're looking for `"argumentName"`, that's the *parameter* name.

Comment: Parameter names and tuple labels are intentionally unobservable in the type system; see the other q/a for more information.